# Effect on Forward Swap Rate from a parallel shift in forward curve

Tags: interest-rates, swaption, volatility-surface, libor-market-model

Can anything be said on how a parallel shift in the forward curve affects the forward swap  curve?

To be more concise, say we have a model estimate of the implied vol for the 2Y-10Y point (2Y expiration, 10y term) of the vol surface following a parallel shift in the forward curve, can I say anything about what the 2Y forward-10Y Swap Rate changes?

Comment: Maybe missing the point here..but if the forward swap curve moves in parallel..then it moves in parallel.

Comment: The forward rate curve moves in parallel. It is not obvious to me from writing the forward swap rate in terms of forward rates that a parallel move would apply. But I might be missing something too

Comment: OK, so let's sat you have a 1y1y fwd swap which fixes exactly on the same days some underlying futures fix. Let's assume all sofrs here. Now if the futures sell off 10 ticks it makes sense that the fwd swap also sell-off 10bps..decomposing 1y1y ~ 2x2y - 1x1y in changes => change in 1y1y is roughly equal to 2x10bps - 1x10bp = 10bps

Comment: Intuitively a swap rate is a weighted average of its fwds. If the fwds all increase by the same amount it would just be reasonable to assume the fwd swap increases by the same..my latex isn't good enough to attempt to even start writing the proof unfort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually depends upon the definition of your parallel curve shift.
I actually **define the curve shift** of a curve based on discount factors to be a shift in the overnight rates on that curve.

```python
from rateslib import *

curve = Curve({dt(2023, 1, 1): 1.0, dt(2035, 1, 1): 0.5}, convention="act365f")

curve.rate(dt(2024, 5, 15), "1b")
# 5.772729343655

curve.shift(10).rate(dt(2024, 5, 15), "1b")
# 5.872729343655    /*  10.00 bps higher  */
```

But a parallel shift of this nature will not translate exactly to 10bps on any arbitrary swap rate due to compounding and second order effects which depend on a number of things, including the frequencies of the legs.

```python
irs = IRS(dt(2025, 1, 1), "10Y", "A")

irs.rate(curves=curve)
# 5.942212540229013

irs.rate(curves=curve.shift(10))
# 6.048193932912746  /*  10.61 bps higher  */
```

Or for a lower frequency with less compounding effect

```python
irs = IRS(dt(2025, 1, 1), "10Y", "M")

irs.rate(curves=curve)
# 5.78619430314164

irs.rate(curves=curve.shift(10))
# 5.88666517710925  /*  10.05 bp higher  */
```