# Why does swap fair rate not change 1:1 with shifted curve?

Tags: swaps, forward-rate, ois, ois-swaps, dv01

I'm trying to calculate things like dv01 for OIS interest rate swaps by shifting the swap curve (by 100bp say) and revaluing swaps on the shifted curve. However, I noticed that the swap rate (QuantLib's `.fairRate()` method in `OISSwap`) does not move 1:1 with the size of the shift. It moves by less. The effect seems to be stronger with swaps with a long forward start, e.g. 10 years. Is there a reason for this? Compounding etc? I'm sure I'm missing something. Thanks in advance

Reproducible example:

```
import QuantLib as ql

as_of_date = ql.Date(14, 11, 2023)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = as_of_date

# Specify overnight index and convention.
sofr = ql.Sofr()
calendar = sofr.fixingCalendar()
business_day_convention = sofr.businessDayConvention()
day_counter = sofr.dayCounter()
fixing_days = sofr.fixingDays()
end_of_month = sofr.endOfMonth()
date_generation = ql.DateGeneration.Backward
payment_lag = 2
settlement_days = 2

# build dummy curve from quotes.
quotes = [
    (1, 0.0200),
    (2, 0.0210),
    (3, 0.0220),
    (4, 0.0230),
    (5, 0.0240),
    (6, 0.0230),
    (7, 0.0220),
    (8, 0.0210),
    (9, 0.0200),
    (10, 0.0190),
    (11, 0.0180),
    (12, 0.0170),
    (13, 0.0160),
    (14, 0.0150),
    (15, 0.0140),
    (16, 0.0130),
    (17, 0.0120),
    (18, 0.0110),
    (19, 0.0100),
    (20, 0.0090),
    (21, 0.0080),
    (22, 0.0070),
    (23, 0.0060),
    (24, 0.0050),
]

helpers = [
    ql.OISRateHelper(
        settlement_days,
        ql.Period(ttm, ql.Years),
        ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(quote)),
        sofr,
    )
    for ttm, quote in quotes
]

bump = 0.01

bumped_helpers = [
    ql.OISRateHelper(
        settlement_days,
        ql.Period(ttm, ql.Years),
        ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(quote - bump)),
        sofr,
    )
    for ttm, quote in quotes
]

curve = ql.PiecewiseCubicZero(
    as_of_date,
    helpers,
    day_counter,
)

bumped_curve = ql.PiecewiseCubicZero(
    as_of_date,
    bumped_helpers,
    day_counter,
)

# Build linkable curve handle and overnight index.
ois_curve_handle = ql.RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle(curve)
discount_swap_engine = ql.DiscountingSwapEngine(ois_curve_handle)
overnight_index = ql.Sofr(ois_curve_handle)

# Swap parameters - 10y starting, 10y tenor swap. $100 notional.
start_date = ql.Date(15, 11, 2033)
end_date = ql.Date(14, 11, 2043)
freq = ql.Period(1, ql.Years)
notional = 100.

# Build payment schedule.
schedule = ql.Schedule(
    start_date,
    end_date,
    freq,
    calendar,
    business_day_convention,
    business_day_convention,
    date_generation,
    end_of_month,
)

# Build swap.
swap = ql.OvernightIndexedSwap(
    ql.Swap.Receiver,
    notional,
    schedule,
    0.0,
    day_counter,
    overnight_index,
    0.0,
    payment_lag,
)
swap.setPricingEngine(discount_swap_engine)

fair_rate = swap.fairRate()

ois_curve_handle.linkTo(bumped_curve)

bumped_fair_rate = swap.fairRate()

>>> fair_rate - bumped_fair_rate
0.0090
```

So the difference between the rates is LESS than 100bp, which seems odd to me.

I'm using python QuantLib==1.32 with Python 3.10

Comment: Convexity is relevant when you are explaining PnL (or the delta), but I think in this example this effect is caused by what you define as a curve shift (the OP swap does not have a 'fixed' rate, but is calculating the mid-market rate from two different curve). I will see if I can find the link

Comment: https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/76963/29443

Comment: In your specific case you are doing this in reverse, you are bumping the calibrating instrument rates by $x$ basis points and then calculating the rate of a swap which may or may not have the same definitions. The root cause will be the same principle.